# TFS Version Control Item extensions

Tags: tfs, controls, version, extensibility

is it possible to extend a TFS Version Control Item with custom fields or properties?
Most entries found are about custom properties on TFS Work Items.

I want to keep a version control Item linked to a record in a database, using a set of custom properties that contain the db/table/primary key of the record.

Thanks, Rine

Comment: When you say "version control item" are you referring to just an item, or a specific revision of an item?  Are you looking at having additional metadata about the item?  Where would you use that data?

Comment: Why not link your record in the database to the version control item, instead?  That is, rather than modifying the 3rd-party system (TFS) to integrate with your software, why not make your software integrate cleanly with the 3rd-party?

Answer (score 1):

Team Foundation Server 2010 introduced a new feature called 'Properties'. Almost every item in TFS, be it a version control file/branch, or a work item can have a property bag associated with it.

What is missing from TFS 2010, is a generic UI to view/set these properties, however you can use the TFS Object Model to view/set them yourself.

For more information, see the following links:

- [Adding Properties to Artifacts within TFS 2010](http://devmatter.blogspot.com/2010/03/adding-properties-to-artifacts-within.html)
- [Using the TFS Property Service to enrich your third party VS tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youhana/archive/2010/05/07/using-the-tfs-property-service-to-enrich-your-third-party-vs-tools-team-member-power-tool-example.aspx)
- [MSDN documentation for Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.IPropertyService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.client.ipropertyservice.aspx).

Comment: It seams you can Get and Set properties by using the IPropertyService interface but how do you delete/remove a property?

Answer (score 0):

You delete a property by setting its value to null.

```
public static void DeleteGenericProperty( this IPropertyService propertyService, 
    string moniker, string propertyName, int version = 1 )
{
     var artifactSpec = new ArtifactSpec(ArtifactKinds.Generic, moniker, version);
     propertyService.SetProperty(artifactSpec, propertyName, (string) null);
}
```